# Привязка PasswordBox к SecureString и его сериализация UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp

Появился следующий вопрос: можно ли каким-то образом привязать PasswordBox к SecureString, следующим образом:

```
SecureString Password { get; set; }
...
<PasswordBox Password="{x:Bind Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Или же необходимо реализовывать метод добавления нового символа к строке с паролем? При этом нужно как то сериализовать объект SecureString, который не поддается Json сериализации. Как можно решить данные проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Если плевать на безопасность, то PasswordBox спокойно байндится к string. Как вариант можно байндить к Tag, а его уже к Password.

Comment: Как ни странно, но в UWP, в отличие от WPF, PasswordBox.Password - является свойством зависимости